# AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName - how to determine?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel, postback, web-parts

I'm having trouble figuring out what 'EventName' asp.net is expecting in the EventName attribute of an AsyncPostBackTrigger.  (The trigger I'm looking at is the drag event on a asp.net WebPart, so if anyone knows the answer based on that, great.)

I read elsewhere that __EVENTTARGET should give me the ID of the control that triggered the event, and __EVENTARGUMENT should give me the name of the event.

To try to figure out what the trigger should be, I've added some code in my page load on postback:

```
Me.txtEventTarget.Value = Me.Page.Request.Params("__EVENTTARGET")
Me.txtEventArg.Value = Me.Page.Request.Params("__EVENTARGUMENT")
```

And when I trigger the postback, I get the following output:

txtEventTarget:
    ctl00$cphDataEntry$zone2

txtEventArg:
    Drag:WebPart_gwpucMyFiles:0

Looks like the 'event arguments' is actually a composite object consisting of three parts:  the name of the event, what looks like part of the ID of the control triggering the event, and a value associated with the event.

But what the heck is ASP.Net doing to the IDs?  I know it does annoying things with underscores and dollar signs, but why is it using a different format for these two variables?  Shouldn't they both contain underscores?

When I view the html source of my page, the control ID looks more like this:
"ctl00_cphDataEntry_WebPartManager1_gwpucMyFiles", except it's never just that ID; the ID of child controls are tacked on.

Anyway, when I try this it doesn't work:

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ctl00_cphDataEntry_WebPartManager1_gwpucMyFiles" EventName="Drag"/>
</Triggers>
```

So, does anyone know what I should put in the AsynchronousPostbackTrigger?  Is the EventName simply "Drag"?  If so, do I need the full ID of my control for the 'ControlID' attribute?  If so, how do I determine the full ID?  Should it be in dollar-sign format or underscore format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ControlID should be the the ID of the web server control. Say you have the following markup inside your ZoneTemplate:

```
<uc1:MyWebPart ID="MyWebPart1" runat="server" />
```

You only need "MyWebPart1" for the ControlID property in the AsynchronousPostbackTrigger, even though in the *rendered HTML* you will see pre-pended IDs of parent controls, with the dollar sign as the delimiter in the "name" attribute and an underscore as a delimiter in the  "id" element.

Neither WebPart nor WebPartZone exposes a "Drag" event, but the WebPartManager exposes the WebPartMoving event, so it seems like that's what you want to handle. Try this:

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="WebPartManager1" EventName="WebPartMoving" />
</Triggers>
```

I'll leave it to you to read up on handling that event and identifying which web part triggered it but see if you can at least get the partial-page postback working first.

Comment: Great thanks.  I did what I should have done in the first place researched the WebPartManager some more.  Turns out WebPartMoving is fired when the web part starts moving; WebPartMoved is fired when it's done.